# How to modify a parameter before it is sent to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I want to modify one of the params in the update function before it gets updated.

I can extract the value doing: `abort house_show_params[:pricing_option].inspect` but I would like to modify it.

I've tried:

```
house_show_params[:pricing_option] = 5
house_show_params.update_attribute(pricing_option: 5)
```

And that did not work.

Update Function

```
def update
    @house_show = current_user.house_show
    respond_to do |format|
      if @house_show.update(house_show_params)
         ......
```

Comment: [ActionController::Parameters](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) is just a hash like object which can be manipulated like a hash. So for example you can do `house_show_params.merge!(pricing_option: 5)`.

Comment: @max i've just tried that and I am still getting the old output

Comment: Then your method of testing is most likely flawed (eg you're doing something stupid outside of the code in question).

Comment: @max I have an enum on the model, and it keeps converting it to the text.   enum pricing_option: [
    :"Free",
    :"Inquire to Discuss",
    :"Fixed Price"
  ]

Comment: @max: `house_show_params.merge!(pricing_option: 5)` not if `house_show_params` is a strong params method. This had cost me an hour or two in the past.

Comment: @max: better to do: `updated_house_show_params = house_show_params.merge(pricing_option: 5)`

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in the model (the controller is not the proper place) using the `write_attribute` method.
For example, if I want my `company_name` field to be stripped before being stored, I would do (in my model):

```
def company_name=(value)
  self[:company_name] = value&.strip
end
```

This would be the same as doing (you can choose whatever way you prefer):

```
def company_name=(value)
  my_model.write_attribute(:company_name, value&.strip)
end
```

This page illustrates the options you have, although you should have your question answered with the two examples above:
https://davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/

Comment: For stripping spaces - yes, a modified setter is a good choice. Victor does something different, though.

Comment: I posted an example about `strip` because the OP doesn't make it clear what kind of update he wants to do.  It works for stripping space or something else (for example setting an enum). Anyway, Victor wasn't clear about his intentions.